# ng2-image-gallery thumbnail undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, image-gallery

I have been following [ng2-image-gallery documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-image-gallery), I've install the npm, added the relevant fields to my `app.module` etc.

Inside my `component.html` I have this:

```
<h2>Image gallery</h2>
<ng2-image-gallery [images]="images" [asThumbnail]="'thumbnail'"></ng2-image-gallery>
```

Inside my `component.ts` I have this:

```
export interface ImageInterface {
    thumbnail?: any; //image src for the thumbnail
    image?: any; //image src for the image 
    text?: string; //optional text to show for the image
    [propName: string]: any;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-section',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: []
})

export class AppComponent {

public images: ImageInterface[] = [];

constructor() {

    var t: ImageInterface;

    t.thumbnail = null;
    t.text = null;
    t.image = null;

    t.thumbnail = 'http://media.istockphoto.com/photos/tree-picture-id543052538';
    t.text = 'cool text';
    t.image = 'http://media.istockphoto.com/photos/tree-picture-id543052538';

    this.images.push(t);


}
}
```

When I run this I get `TypeError: Cannot set property 'thumbnail' of undefined` I'm relatively new to Angular2 so if someone can suggest what I need to do to get this up and running it'll be highly appreciated.

Comment: dont know about the problem but i think this one is wrong `[asThumbnail]="'thumbnail'"` use instead `[asThumbnail]="thumbnail"`

Comment: @PardeepJain same error unfortunately.